# How can I find the database directory of Thunderbird?

Tags: security, thunderbird

I want to automate loading a security module in Mozilla Thunderbird. For this I should know the application  directory so that I can edit the database.

In Windows we have a function `SHGetFolderPathA()` which returns the user's application data directory. How to find the same in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All personal files are stored under `/home/$USER/` inside hidden directories.

For Thunderbird that could be 2 locations...

```
/home/$USER/.thunderbird/
/home/$USER/.mozilla-thunderbird/
```

Ubuntu uses the 1st nowadays.

- There will be a subdirectory named after your profile.
- All of the messages for an account are stored in a subdirectory named after the mail server.